# PostgresQL password being asked for and not working, despite re-installation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, passwords

**NOTE** I'm running Windows 7 and postgres version 9.3.

I'm having the frustrating problem that I misplaced my password for postgresQL. After trying to discover how to recover the password, to no avail, I decided that I should uninstall and then re-install postgres. The installation process went smoothly, and I was prompted for a password towards the end of the process.

However, after this re-installation and new password, I typed `psql` into the terminal and was prompted for `password:`, but the password that I enter, the new one that I just created, doesn't work. I'm not sure if perhaps the old password is stored somewhere? I've tried other things, like using `su` before typing in `postgres` or `psql` (which doesn't work on windows..."'su' is not recognized as an internal or external command").

The main issue is that I *actually* need the password, because I'm using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), and need to connect using `var conString = "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";`. I tried putting in my post-re-install `username` and `password` in there, but I get the error message `error fetching client from pool { [error: password authentication failed for user "myUserName"]`

Any ideas of why the new password isn't working or how to get the password and get postgres running?

Thanks!

Comment: are you specifying the user when you connect with psql?  I don't know much about windows, but, I would try the windows equiv of: psql -Upostgres and then enter your password.  The password depends on the account.  There are lots of different ways to do this, but that should get you in.

Comment: I'm not specifying the username. Postgres has given me the username that is the system username, from when I log on to Windows. I'll try to find the equivalent

Comment: I was able to get into postgresQL using `psql -U postgres` ! So now I'll just need to find the commands to create a new user and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

What you have to do is

1) type in `psql -U postgres` to the console. This will get you through to postgresQL (hopefully - if not, maybe your `pg_hba.conf` file, or something else, needs to be changed).

2)Type `CREATE USER whateverUsernameYouWant;` (obviously setting your own username)

3)Type `ALTER USER whateverUsernameYouWant WITH PASSWORD 'thisIsMyNewPassword'` (again, setting your password and using the username you entered earlier);

4) In the node.js file that I'm working on, I set var `conString = "postgres://whateverUsernameYouWant:thisIsMyNewPassword@localhost/database"`;

5) After you create a database (using `create DATABASE yourDatabaseName OWNER yourUsername;`), to access the database AFTER EXITING postgres simply type in `psql yourDatabaseName yourUsername` and everything should be peachy :)

Comment: yup, that will do it.  postgres and windows will assert the 'current user' that is logged in as one way to provide the user you want to log in as.  There is more to it, though.  For example, on unix there is a pg_hba.conf file, this is used to see how to authenticate. Different classes of users (for example local users vs. network users) can have different rules (like local doesn't need a password (trusted) to network does). good to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The “postgres” user already created in your windows user account. You can
reset the password at the operating system level. To do this on Windows, do
the following:

1. Right click on the 'My Computer'
2. Choose 'Manage' from the pop up menu
3. Expand the 'Local Users and Groups' folder
4. Expand the 'Users' folder
5. On the right hand side of the screen, you will see all the users defined
   on the system.
6. You can right click on the “postgres” user name and choose 'Set Password'
   and then change it to something else Apply the same password of “postgres”
   user at the time installation level and installation goes successfully.